# Diagnostic Process ends with exit code 1 but same action on command prompt works

Tags: c#, process, gdal, diagnostics

My code uses a C# Diagnostic Process to run a GDAL process.
This process ends with an exit code 1.
But running from a command prompt works.
Where's my mistake?

Already tested (see code below):

- files to transform exists,
- directory to write to exists and "My programme" has access rights,
- the GDAL library exists.

This is my code:

```
private string AddSrs(string tempFile, string User)
{
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

string geoserverDatadir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["geoserverDatadir"];
string dirOut = Path.Combine(geoserverDatadir, User, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
string fileOut = Path.Combine(dirOut, (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempFile) + ".geoTiff"));
Directory.CreateDirectory(dirOut);
if (File.Exists(fileOut))
{
    File.Delete(fileOut);
}

string binDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["binDirectory"];
startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(binDirectory, "gdal_translate.exe");
string args = String.Format(@"-a_srs EPSG:28992 {0}{1}{0} {0}{2}{0}", "\"", tempFile, fileOut);
startInfo.Arguments = args;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;

if(!File.Exists(startInfo.FileName))
{
    _log.Error("file not exists: " + startInfo.FileName));
}
if (!File.Exists(tempFile))
{
    _log.Error("file not exists: " + tempFile));
}
if (!Directory.Exists(dirOut))
{
    _log.Error("directory not exists: " + dirOut));
}
try
{
    // Attempt to get a list of security permissions from the folder. 
    // This will raise an exception if the path is read only or do not have access to view the permissions. 
    System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity ds = Directory.GetAccessControl(dirOut);
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
    _log.Error("no access rights for directory: " + dirOut));
}

try
{
    process.Start();
    int processTimeOut = 1000;
    if (!process.WaitForExit(processTimeOut))
    {
        process.Kill();
        _log.Error("Process killed by timeOut: " + processTimeOut));
        return string.Empty;
     }
     else
     {
        var exitCode = process.ExitCode;
        _log.Error("Process ended. Exitcode: " + exitCode));
        return fileOut;
      }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      _log.Error(ex.Message));
      _log.Error(ex.StackTrace));
      return string.Empty;
  }
```

}

EDIT:
This is the full command as logged in my logfile:

```
D:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal_translate.exe -a_srs EPSG:28992 "D:\data\Temp\Merkator\Hengelo Veldwijk Zuid Revisie.temp" "D:\data\Geoserver\data\Merkator\aa84dc6d-aff2-4254-975a-3ede8eea5c6d\Hengelo Veldwijk Zuid Revisie.geoTiff"
```

And this is the same command pasted in commandline (works with and without admin rights):

```
C:\Users\Administrator>D:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal_translate.exe -a_srs EPSG:28992 "D:\data\Temp\Merkator\Hengelo Veldwijk Zuid Revisie.temp" "D:\data\Geoserver\data\Merkator\aa84dc6d-aff2-4254-975a-3ede8eea5c6d\Hengelo Veldwijk Zuid Revisie.geoTiff"
Input file size is 1273, 378
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

INFO:
The problem exists on a (virtual) server. On my computer (debug-mode) this code works fine.

Comment: Are you sure that an exit code of 1 means failure?

Comment: Please, please, please remove the duplication. It's impossible to read this code. What's the point of repeating `GetType().Name` all the time? Just get it once and store it in a variable. It's impossible to find the line where you run the command in all this

Comment: What do the arguments look like? BTW instead of `string args = String.Format(@"-a_srs EPSG:28992 {0}{1}{0} {0}{2}{0}", "\"", tempFile, fileOut);` you should probably write `string args = String.Format("-a_srs EPSG:28992 \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", tempFile, fileOut);` or `string args = $"-a_srs EPSG:28992 \"{tempFile}\" \"{fileOut}\"";` in C# 7

Comment: This is the full command as logged in my logfile: D:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal_translate.exe -a_srs EPSG:28992 "D:\data\Temp\Merkator\Hengelo Veldwijk Zuid Revisie.temp" "D:\data\Geoserver\data\Merkator\aa84dc6d-aff2-4254-975a-3ede8eea5c6d\Hengelo Veldwijk Zuid Revisie.geoTiff"

Comment: Be sure you set the `WorkingDirectory` property of your `startInfo` object.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway This is it. Setting the Working Directory did the trick. Tanx.